# Xamarin Form IOS Webview load url embended into app

Tags: ios, xamarin, https, webview

When i trying load url into webview, its wokr fine in android. The HTML code is embended into my app  [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdAyh.jpg). But IOS open in Safari.
How embended in IOS? [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTuc5.png)

simple code. Its work only in android.

> ```
>  new WebView{
>                     
>                     Source =  new UrlWebViewSource() { Url = URL},            
>                     HorizontalOptions ...
>                 };
> ```

Its working on ios too,  but really slow

> ```
>  new WebView{
>                     
>                     Source =   new HtmlWebViewSource() {  Html=new WebClient().DownloadString(URL),            
>                     HorizontalOptions ...
>                 };
> ```

Comment: have you read the docs?  They explicitly cover how to load local content.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=macos#local-html-content

Comment: Yes. I readed it. But didnt found answare.

Comment: Did you try to load local file or remote url in webview?

Comment: Work fine in latest xamarin forms package. I had just update nuget.